# Can an extension function always be translated to a member?

Tags: kotlin

I have some extension functions I would like to move into to member functions. But I'm not sure how to do so, especially with the nested generic type chain.

```
import Y.*

abstract class File<T>

open class Y private constructor() {
  open class localhost_ {
    @JvmName("usr") operator fun div(a: usr.Companion) = usr<localhost_>()
    @JvmName("bin") operator fun div(a: bin.Companion) = bin<localhost_>()
    @JvmName("etc") operator fun div(a: etc.Companion) = etc<localhost_>()

    companion object: localhost_()
  }

  open class bin<T>: File<T>() { companion object }
  open class sh<T>: File<T>() { companion object }
  open class etc<T>: File<T>() { companion object }
  open class vim<T>: File<T>() { companion object }
  open class usr<T>: File<T>() { companion object }
  open class local<T>: File<T>() { companion object }

  companion object { fun uri(path: Any) = println(path) }
}

operator fun bin<localhost_>.div(a: sh.Companion) = sh<bin<localhost_>>()
operator fun bin<usr<localhost_>>.div(a: vim.Companion) = vim<bin<usr<localhost_>>>()
operator fun etc<localhost_>.div(a: vim.Companion) = vim<etc<localhost_>>()
operator fun usr<localhost_>.div(a: bin.Companion) = bin<usr<localhost_>>()
operator fun usr<localhost_>.div(a: local.Companion) = local<usr<localhost_>>()
operator fun local<usr<localhost_>>.div(a: bin.Companion) = bin<local<usr<localhost_>>>()

/**
 * localhost_/
 * ├── bin/
 * │   └── sh
 * ├── etc/
 * │   └── vim
 * └── usr/
 *     ├── bin/
 *     │   └── vim
 *     └── local/
 *         └── bin/
 */

fun main(a: Array<String>) {
  //Compiles!
  Y.uri(localhost_)
  Y.uri(localhost_/bin)
  Y.uri(localhost_/bin/sh)
  Y.uri(localhost_/etc)
  Y.uri(localhost_/etc/vim)
  Y.uri(localhost_/usr)
  Y.uri(localhost_/usr/bin/vim)
  Y.uri(localhost_/usr/local)
  Y.uri(localhost_/usr/local/bin)


  //Does not compile!
  Y.uri(localhost_/local)
  Y.uri(localhost_/bin/vim)
  Y.uri(localhost_/sh)
  Y.uri(localhost_/bin/local)
  Y.uri(localhost_/etc/local)
  Y.uri(localhost_/etc/sh)
  Y.uri(localhost_/usr/local/usr)
}
```

How do you translate an extension function whose receiver has a generic type to a member function? Is there a way to put the operator functions inside the classes, or are extensions the only way to achieve this? I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
open class usr<T>: File<T>() {
    operator fun <T: usr<localhost_>> div(a: local.Companion) = local<T>()
    operator fun <T: usr<localhost_>> div(a: bin.Companion) = bin<T>()

    companion object
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me just say: that is a rather obvious misuse of the division operator function. A division that simply ignores the divisor just to use the `/`? However to be honest, it is also a funny way to use `/` in the code ;-) Still, I can not recommend it. Look at your code. You have lots of unused divisors now ;-) Disclaimer aside, lets solve your problem.

The solution to your specific problem is not so nice as you may think. What you do with the extension functions is not that easily movable to a member function. The reason why: you narrow the usage of the extension function to a specfic generic type. If you want the same as member, you need to narrow down it there too. If you look at what extension functions rather are (static method calls), you may need the same structure also in the implementing classes again. The following for example works, but is not narrowing down the hierarchy:

```
open class usr<T>: File<T>() {
  operator fun div(a: local.Companion) = local<usr<T>>()
  operator fun div(a: bin.Companion) = bin<usr<T>>()
  companion object
}
```

So /...anything/usr/local might work, if you allow `usr` to be under `...anything`.
To answer your general question "can extension functions always be translated to a member function?" It depends. Surely not 1:1 as soon as generics are used. Maybe this leads to a new class hierarchy and removes your generics information in the end ;-) But also that will probably not end up nice.

But, as we wrote a lot... here was the previous solution (when there was still written "does not compile!" in the second part, but now adapted to "must not compile!" ;-)

As you may have recognized, your type `T` can not be inferred. But as you already thought to use `T : usr<localhost_>>` why didn't you omit the generic type information in the first place?

If you remove it anywhere your code will still work as you expect and to be honest, you did not even once use anything that would be beneficial with generics ;-)

If you are there, also omit the extension functions as you will not need them too anymore and if you wanted to narrow what is possible to call (e.g. `localhost_/usr/local/bin` should be allowed, but `localhost_/usr/local/usr/local/bin` not) then generics are probably not the way to go.

Here is your example without generics and without extension functions:

```
abstract class File
open class Y private constructor() {
    open class localhost_ {
        @JvmName("usr") operator fun div(a: usr.Companion) = usr()
        @JvmName("bin") operator fun div(a: bin.Companion) = bin()
        @JvmName("etc") operator fun div(a: etc.Companion) = etc()
        companion object {
            operator fun div(a: usr.Companion) = usr()
            operator fun div(a: bin.Companion) = bin()
            operator fun div(a: etc.Companion) = etc()
        }
    }

    // hierarchies are also built as class hierarchies
    open class bin: File() {
        operator fun div(a: sh.Companion) = sh()
        open class sh: File() { companion object }
        companion object }
    open class etc: File() {
        operator fun div(a: etc.vim.Companion) = etc.vim()
        open class vim: File() { companion object }
        companion object }
    open class usr: File() {
        operator fun div(a: usr.bin.Companion) = usr.bin()
        operator fun div(a: usr.local.Companion) = usr.local()
        open class bin: File() {
            operator fun div(a: usr.bin.vim.Companion) = usr.bin.vim()
            open class vim: File() { companion object }
            companion object }
        open class local : File() {
            operator fun div(a: local.bin.Companion) = local.bin()
            open class bin : File() { companion object }
            companion object }
        companion object }

    companion object { fun uri(path: Any) = println(path) }
}
```

However, calling it does really not look nice (as you then need to import the appropriate type... you could still put leafs outside the class hierarchy, but that's really not the same ;-) (now `vim` is a leaf, but what if you have a folder `vim` later?)

```
Y.uri(localhost_)
Y.uri(localhost_)
Y.uri(localhost_ / bin)
Y.uri(localhost_ / bin / bin.sh)
Y.uri(localhost_ / etc)
Y.uri(localhost_ / etc / etc.vim)
Y.uri(localhost_ / usr)
Y.uri(localhost_ / usr / usr.bin / usr.bin.vim)
Y.uri(localhost_ / usr / usr.local)
Y.uri(localhost_ / usr / usr.local / usr.local.bin)
```

But again, as you did not use the division as division, you may still would be better of omitting it (as you don't even get beautiful/helpful code completion), e.g. by either using:

```
Y.uri("localhost_/usr/local/bin")
```

or with reified types and a `StringBuilder` concatenating your paths:

```
abstract class File {
  val uri = StringBuilder()

  inline fun <reified T> append() : T {
    val clazz = T::class
    uri.append(clazz.simpleName).append("/")
    return clazz.java.newInstance()
  }
}
open class usr: File() {
  fun local() = append<local>()
  fun bin() = append<bin>()
}
```

Which you can call as follows:

```
Y.uri(localhost().usr().local().bin())
// or simply localhost().usr().local().bin().uri
```

You get even useful code completion this way.

Here is an example, which I still don't recommend, which uses a mixture of the operator and a reified function in the back:

```
open class usr: File() {
  operator fun div(a : local.Companion) = append<local>()
  operator fun div(a : bin.Companion) = append<bin>()
  companion object
}
```

Note that you can also mix the refied types with your operator, but you need an `inline` function then. I did not elaborate on that further ;-)
And as you noted yourself, you can even use properties then... Really lots of things you should rather consider instead of misusing generics and the division ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and thoughtful reply. I am intrigued by your solution, but, after reading it several times, I am unable to see how it solves the problem. Probably I am not clever enough.You wrote, "why didn't you omit the generic type information in the first place? If you remove it anywhere your code will still work as you expect". This statement is simply untrue (try it). The main function must work as described.

Comment: I am open to using function invocations, but again, the main function must work as described. Here is the specification using your syntax. Compiles: `localhost().bin()`, `localhost().bin().sh()`, `localhost().usr().bin()`. Does not compile: `localhost().usr().bin().sh()`.

Comment: For reference, you may find my solution here: https://github.com/breandan/yuri/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/Y.kt

Comment: I am pretty sure that I tested all of your main entries. Will have a look at it later. Maybe I missed a copy ;-)

Comment: It is important when verifying your solution that all of the "Compiles!" statements compile AND none of the "Does not compile!" statements compile.

Comment: Just rechecked. With the proposed generic-less solution (code posting 1) both the "Compiles!"- and "Does not compile!"-part can be compiled and run. If you tried a mixture of the other code postings please note, that they are not complete but rather an excerpt of how things can be accomplished.

Comment: Thank you again for considering my problem. I really appreciate it! But you are still missing the point. Let me try to be as clear as possible. If you uncomment any of the last seven statements in this file and the program still compiles, your solution is not to spec: https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/317657goaabar159aj9g5d7tre/6rtvrip7q85sfdstrv9258c97t

Comment: Ok.. you rather wanted to say "must not compile" instead of "does not compile". Huge difference! Ok.. I'll think of something and probably return on 2nd.

Comment: That was the main reason I omitted everything in the first place ;-) Nonetheless, don't you think that is rather way to complicated just to show that it works? ;-)

Comment: The full file tree is unnecessary, perhaps I should have distilled the original post to a shorter example. I have provided the simplest possible form in this comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586423/can-an-extension-function-always-be-translated-to-a-member?noredirect=1#comment90175898_51590447

Comment: You correctly recognized the essence of the problem in your reply, "If you wanted to narrow what is possible to call (e.g. `localhost_/usr/local/bin` should be allowed, but `localhost_/usr/local/usr/local/bin` not)"

Comment: But still. It's a challenge nonetheless ;-) It could work out, but at the end I am not sure whether it will look good..

Comment: Regarding your comment about autocompletion: yes, this is a valid point. Which is why I am not especially concerned about the `/` operator. This is simply sugar. On the other hand, we should not need to constrain the syntax to fit the IDE. If the syntax is valid, then the IDE can adapt to our use case if there is a legitimate need to do so. From our standpoint, the tools are invisible, and can be fixed at a later point.

Comment: If you want to be even more concise, you can use properties to avoid the unnecessary `()`s from your second example.

Comment: Yeah, something's still not working. I was excited to try it!

Comment: OK, updated the answer... short version: yes! it can be accomplished! you may however need to reflect it in your class hierarchy then (or have the appropriate methods in place).

Comment: oh dear... my mistake... check it again... forgot the `<usr`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177260/discussion-between-roland-and-breandan).